# In a modular arithmetic equation, how to find 'a' given a range?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Say I have an equation in the form

$$a\bmod b = c$$

I know $b$ and $c$ I'm given a range $(d,e)$ (where $d$ and $e$ are integers). How can I find all values of $a$ that satisfy the inequality $d \le a \le e$?

Comment: Well,  "a = c (mod b)" means $a = c + bn$ for some integer n.  Now you just need to solve for n given your range.

Comment: @lulu Right, my problem is finding an algorithm of some sort that will calculate that between a range

Comment: Well, first solve for $c+bn = d$ (probably not an integer). the least n that works is the least integer greater than or equal to that value.  Similarly solving $c+bn= e$ gives you an upper bound.  All the integers in between will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all multiples of $b$ that are between $d-c$ and $e-c$, and add $c$ to each of them.

The reason is that such an $a$ can be written $c+kb,\enspace k\in\mathbf Z$. Write the range inequalities:
$$d\le c+kb\le e\iff d-c\le kb\le  e-c.$$
Once you have all $kb$ that satisfie these conditions, by definition, $a= kb+c$.

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation as to why this works?

Comment: Here are the details. Is it clear?

Comment: I do apologize, I'm kind of new at this. What does the '⟺' symbol mean?

Comment: You're welcome. It means ‘if and only if’, or ‘ is logically equivalent’. I just followed the usual rules for inequalities.